# How do I retrieve image full url from database where column contain array of images?

Tags: php, laravel

I have stored an array of images in the database column name images like this:

```
'images' => [
    '80011701010550.jpg',
    '80011701010550_3.jpg',
    '80011701010550_4.jpg'
],
```

I have done like this:

```
$list = App\ProductTemplate::select('product_templates_id','name', 'keywords', 'images')->get();
```

It gives me result like this:

```
"list": [{
    "product_templates_id": 1,
    "name": "Daawat Brown Basmati Rice",
    "keywords": "basmati Daawat rice chawal tandul tandool",
    "images": [
        "60011805049946.jpg"
    ]
}]
```

I want to retrieve all list containing image full URL of the first image only. I want to append this full URL attribute with a list. So how do I achieve this with Laravel?

I want result like this:

```
"list": [{
    "product_templates_id": 1,
    "name": "Daawat Brown Basmati Rice",
    "keywords": "basmati Daawat rice chawal tandul tandool",
    "images_full_url": "http:://localhost/images/60011805049946.jpg"
}]
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You can use `mutarors` and `accessors` functionality of `eloquent` in laravel.

Comment: Why not simply add the URL wherever you output the image names? As you are changing the whole stuff anyways (from an images array to a single value `images_full_url`), it should not be too hard to add such logic there

Comment: Problem solved by using mutators

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use like
in `ProductTemplate.php` model

```php
protected $appends = ['images_full_url'];

function getImageFullUrlAttribute()
{
    $fullUrl = [];
    foreach ($this->images as $image) {
        array_push($fullUrl, asset('images/' . $image));
    }
    return $fullUrl;
}
```

It appends `images_full_url` to collection

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json